# MATLAB でフラグを制御する方法について

Tags: c, matlab

2秒ごとに3回「Transmit」を表示しながら、その期間同様に「Plot」を別の関数で表示させようとしています。
MATLABのバージョンはR2017bで、実行環境はWindowsです。

for ループが終了するまでの期間は、plotData 関数を続けて、for ループを終了したら、プロット関数の実行も停止するようにしたいです。

フラグ"stat" がtrueの時にプロットを続ける、フラグが false のときにプロットを停止という制御をしていますが、機能せず、どのように修正したらいいかわからない状態です。
plotはどうしても関数呼び出しをする必要があり、これらの制御方法についてアドバイスをいただきたいです。

```
%data
global accumulateData

%status
global stat
stat = true;
if(stat == true)
    %h = addlistener(s, 'DataAvailable', @plotData);
    h =  @plotData;  
end

%Transmit 3 times every 2 seconds
for i = (1:3)-1

    if i == 3
        fprintf("end\n");
        pause(2)
        stat = false;
        exit();
    end
    fprintf("Transmit\n");
    pause(2);
end


function plotData(src, event)
   %plot(event.TimeStamps, event.Data);
   fprintf("plot\n");
end
```

出力

```
>> untitled
Transmit
Transmit
Transmit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tic`関数と`toc`関数を利用して、経過時間を計算すればいいのではないでしょうか。

```
% ループ終了条件
repeat = 3;
count = 0;

% 開始時間の設定
starttime = tic;

% 次に transmit する時間
nextTrans = 0;

while true
    elapsedTime = toc(starttime); % 経過時間の計算
    if elapsedTime >= nextTrans   % transmit する時間になったかどうかチェック
        disp("transmit")
        count = count + 1;

　　　　 % repeat 回 transmit したらループを抜ける
        if count >= repeat
            break
        end

        % 次の transmit 時間の設定
        nextTrans = nextTrans + 2;
    end 

    % ここで plot
end

disp("end")
```

Comment: ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。「%ここでplot」との明記は、関数呼び出し（h = addlistener(s, 'DataAvailable', @plotData);など）を行い、while loop外でfunctionを定義するという理解で正しいでしょうか。

Comment: @NPP plotの仕方については、質問文に書かれていなかったので考慮していません。また、データの取り方については、提示されたコードは断片しかなく、具体的な仕様が記述されていないので、それをどのようにグラフにすれば良いかは、わかりかねます。